# User defined function for getting absolute value

Tags: python, function, absolute-value

Using **Wing ide 3.3.5**

How would I write a function my_abs(value) that returns the absolute value of its x, without using the built-in abs function in Python.

**For example:**

```
Test                Result
print(my_abs(3.5))  3.5
print(my_abs(-7.0)) 7.0
```

Comment: How is the IDE possibly relevant? Do you understand what `abs` does?

Answer (score 4):

A snarky answer would be to use the built-in `__abs__()` function instead:

```
>>> print((-7.0).__abs__())
7.0
```

---

Here is a naïve one-liner (basically equivalent to @Nabin's answer):

```
def simple_abs(num):
    return -num if num < 0 else num
```

---

However, it turns out that there is a bug, because

```
>>> -0.0 < 0
False
>>> simple_abs(-0.0)
-0.0                        ← Buggy
>>> abs(-0.0)
0.0                         ← Correct
```

It turns out that [testing for negative zero in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4083401/3496801) is hard to do.  One possible test is `str(-0.0) == '-0.0'`.  Here's what @JasonS helped me come up with:

```
import math

def my_abs(num):
    return -num if math.copysign(1, num) < 0 else num
```

Or, in longer, more readable form:

```
def my_abs(num):
    if math.copysign(1, num) < 0:
        return -num
    else:
        return num
```

Comment: +1 for `__abs__()` though the discussion of negative zero is also interesting.

Comment: I don't think you need to `str(num)` though, think about `math.copysign(1, num)`. Or is that as cheaty as `__abs__`?

Comment: @JasonS I like that. Incorporated in Rev 2.

Answer (score 1):

A simple **algorithm** would be:

```
if number<0:
    return number*-1
else:
    return number
```

You have to check if the number is negative. Is so, then multiply it with -1 and return. Or you have to return the number without alteration.