# Calculate the sin, cos, tan with math module?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

My Problem is that I don't get the same calculations on python, than on my calculator:

Calculations on Calculator in Degree mode:

```
cos(270)
```

that gives me:

```
0
```

When I put the same calculations in python:

```
print(math.cos(math.radians(270)))
```

I get something completely different:

```
-1.8369701987210297e-16
```

I guess it is a very simple Mistake I made, please help me....

Comment: It is just a rounding error. The value you are getting of `-1.8369701987210297e-16` is extremely close to 0 and can just be interpreted as that way.

Comment: To be clear, that `e-16` is short for "multiplied by 10 to the power of negative 16", a very small number (15 zeroes after the decimal point).

Comment: Seems like another variation of the much duplicated [is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4996248)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like is described in the comments, this is just a rounding error. `-1.8369701987210297e-16` is extremely close to 0 and can be viewed as such.

If you want a number such as your expected behavior, round the result as so using `round(value, decimalplaces)`. Let's round to 2 decimal spots:

```py
>>> print('cos(270) is', round(math.cos(math.radians(270)), 2))
cos(270) is -0.0
```

Comment: BTW, about the `-0.0`: [negative zero in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4083401/4518341)

Comment: To be even more clear, the rounding error is on cos input already, you can not represent pi with a finite number of bits after floating point...