# Sklearn.linear_model.Lasso returns coefficients that are both +0 and -0?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

After training an ML model using https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso, when I print out the coefficients, I can see that some of them give 0.00000000e+00 while others are -0.00000000e+00.

Is there a reason for this difference? At the end of the day, I am assuming they are both coefficient=0. (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear regression models can compute negative coefficients and `-0` is the result of rounding originally negative numbers. A comparison like `-0 == 0` will yield `True` and they behave the same for most operations. However, in operations where the sign is important it will make a difference. Thus, it would account as information loss to drop the `-` sign.

For more information on `-0` and its behavior in Python, I refer to the answer(s) of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083401/negative-zero-in-python).

Comment: @programmer12 and [IEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) allows for this [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) representation.