# The numpy angle function returns different answers for the same input?

Tags: python, numpy, angle

I am using Python 3.7.7 and numpy 1.19.1. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
a = 55.74947517067784019673 + 0j
print(f'{-a == -1 * a}, {np.angle(-a)}, {np.angle(-1 * a)}')
```

and this is the output:

```
True, -3.141592653589793, 3.141592653589793
```

I have two questions:

1. Why does the angle function give different outputs for the same input?
2. According to the documentation, the angle output range is `(-pi, pi]`, so why is one of the outputs `-np.pi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1430-L1480) of the `np.angle`, it uses the function `np.arctan2`. Now, according to the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html#id1), `np.arctan2` uses the underlying C library, which has the following rule:

*Note that +0 and -0 are distinct floating point numbers, as are +inf and -inf.*

which results in different behavior when calculating using `+/-0`. So, in this case, the rule is:

```
y: +/- 0
x: <0
angle: +/- pi
```

Now, if you try:

```
a = 55.74947517067784019673
print(f'{-a == -1 * a}, {np.angle(-a)}, {np.angle(-1 * a)}')
#True, 3.141592653589793, 3.141592653589793
```

and if you try:

```
a = 55.74947517067784019673 + 0j
print(-a)
#(-55.74947517067784-0j)
print(-1*a)
#(-55.74947517067784+0j)
print(f'{-a == -1 * a}, {np.angle(-a)}, {np.angle(-1 * a)}')
#True, -3.141592653589793, 3.141592653589793
```

Which is inline with the library protocol.

As for your second question, I guess it is a typo/mistake since the [`np.arctan2` doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) says:

*Array of angles in radians, in the range **[-pi, pi]**. This is a scalar if both x1 and x2 are scalars.*

**Explanation of `-a` vs. `-1*a`**:

To start with, `55.74947517067784019673 + 0j` is **NOT** construction of a complex number and merely **addition of a float to a complex number** (to construct a complex number explicitly use `complex(55.74947517067784019673, 0.0)` and beware that integers do not have signed zeros and only floats have). `-a` is simply reverting the sign and quite self explanatory. Lets see what happens when we calculate `-1*a`:

For simplicity assume `a = 55.5 + 0j`

- First `a = 55.5+0j` converts to `complex(55.5, 0.0)`
- Second `-1` equals to `complex(-1.0, 0.0)`
- Then `complex(-1.0, 0.0)*complex(55.5, 0.0)` equals to `complex((-1.0*55.5 - 0.0*0.0), (-1.0*0.0 + 0.0*55.5))` equals to `complex((-55.5 - 0.0), (-0.0 + 0.0))` which then equals to `complex(-55.5, 0.0)`.

Note that `-0.0+0.0` equals to `0.0` and the sign rule only applies to multiplication and division as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083401/negative-zero-in-python) and quoted in comments below. To better understand it, see this:

```
print(complex(-1.0, -0.0)*complex(55.5, 0.0))
#(-55.5-0j)
```

where the imaginary part is `(-0.0*55.5 - 1.0*0.0) = (-0.0 - 0.0) = -0.0`

Comment: BTW any idea why `-a` and `-1 * a` are not identically equal in the first place?

Comment: @Julien They explain similar situation in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083401/negative-zero-in-python

Comment: @Ehsan In the answer in your link it it says "When a multiplication or division involves a signed zero, the usual sign rules apply in computing the sign of the answer." So the question that Julian asked is not answered. I would expect that -1 * (0+0j) results in (-0-0j), so why is it (-0+0j)?

Comment: @WimvanderMeer It exactly explains the issue you are addressing. Your misconception comes from the understanding of complex numbers. I will add an edit to explain it more.

Comment: @WimvanderMeer I tried my best to explain clearly what is going on in the edit on the post. Feel free to accept/upvote the answer and close the question if your question is resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Nice and sneaky. I naively thought real * complex would merely distribute like scalar * vector multiplication... As usual always question your assumptions. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

For 1) print `-a` and `-1*a`, you'll see they are different.

```
-a
Out[4]: (-55.74947517067784-0j)

-1*a
Out[5]: (-55.74947517067784+0j) # note +0j not -0j
```

Without knowing the details of the numpy implementation, the sign of the imaginary part is probably used to compute the angle... which could explain why this degenerate case gives different results.

For 2) this looks like a bug or a doco mistake to me then...

Comment: Not sure if 2) technically counts as a mistake in the docs. 
`pi = -3.141592653589793..... <-3.141592653589793` in a mathematical sense. So -3.141592653589793 is in fact in `(-pi, pi]`.

Comment: I think it's fair to assume that when the docs says `pi` they mean its numerical representation `np.pi` not its true transcendental value. This is the only thing any programmer will care about, and in that sense the doc would be wrong... At the very least it looks like a nasty wart.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I modified the question to indicate that I mean -np.pi.