# f-string formatting: display number sign?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, f-string

Basic question about python f-strings, but couldn't find out the answer: how to force sign display of a float or integer number? i.e. what f-string makes `3` displayed as `+3`?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like a kind of row display? (Without any statement?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From Docs:

- [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)(Emphasis mine):

> | Option | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | **`'+'`** | indicates that a **sign should be used** for both positive as well as negative numbers. |
> | `'-'` | indicates that a sign should be used only for negative numbers (this is the default behavior). |

Example from docs:

```py
>>> '{:+f}; {:+f}'.format(3.14, -3.14)  # show it always
'+3.140000; -3.140000'
>>> '{:-f}; {:-f}'.format(3.14, -3.14)  # show only the minus -- same as '{:f}; {:f}'
'3.140000; -3.140000'
>>> '{:+} {:+}'.format(10, -10)
'+10 -10'
```

Above examples using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```py
>>> f'{3.14:+f}; {-3.14:+f}'
'+3.140000; -3.140000'
>>> f'{3.14:-f}; {-3.14:-f}'
'3.140000; -3.140000'
>>> f'{10:+} {-10:+}'
'+10 -10'
```

One caveat while printing `0` as [0 is neither positive nor negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0#Mathematics). In python, `+0 = -0 = 0`.

```
>>> f'{0:+} {-0:+}'
'+0 +0'
>>> f'{0.0:+} {-0.0:+}'
'+0.0 -0.0'
```

`0.0` and `-0.0` are different objects<sup>1</sup>.

- [0 in Computer Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0#Computer_science)(Emphasis mine):

> In some computer hardware [signed number representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations), **zero has two distinct representations**, a positive one grouped with the positive numbers and a negative one grouped with the negatives; this kind of dual representation is known as signed zero, with the latter form sometimes called negative zero.

---

<sub>1. [Negative 0 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4083401). Also check out [Signed Zero (-0)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%920_%28number%29)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

You can use `:+` in f-string

```
number=3
print(f"{number:+}")
```

Output
`+3`

Answer (score 3):

Fastest solution: `f"{['', '+'][number>0]}{number}"`

```
numbers = [+3, -3]

for number in numbers:
    print(f"{['', '+'][number>0]}{number}")
```

Result:

```
+3
-3
```

EDIT: Small time analysis:

```
import time

numbers = [+3, -3] * 1000000

t0 = time.perf_counter()
[print(f"{number:+}", end="") for number in numbers]
t1 = time.perf_counter()
[print(f"{number:+.2f}", end="") for number in numbers]
t2 = time.perf_counter()
[print(f"{['', '+'][number>0]}{number}", end="") for number in numbers]
t3 = time.perf_counter()
print("\n" * 50)
print("""number:+ : """ + str(round(t1-t0, 2)) + "s")
print("""number:+.2f : """ + str(round(t2-t1, 2)) + "s")
print("""['', '+'][number>0] : """ + str(round(t3-t2, 2)) + "s")
```

Result:

```
number:+ : 1.43s
number:+.2f : 1.98s
['', '+'][number>0] : 1.23s
```

It looks like I have the fastest solution for integers.

Comment: A bit cryptic, but I like this solution, using the result of number>0 as the index! Very clever.

Comment: clever and indeed cryptic. 

number>0  will evaluate to True or False.  Python conveniently hard wires True to 1, and False to 0.

`['', '+'][number>0]`  is thus a subscripted list, and the surrounding {} force evaluation.

Comment: Of note, this can also be used to place parenthesis (or anything else) around a negative number (financial etc) e.g. `f"{['(', ''][n>=0]}{n:3.4}{[')', ''][n>=0]}"` -> `(-2.455)` - I couldn't find any other way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a sign with an f-string using `f"{x:+}"`, where `x` is the int/float variable you need to add the sign to. For more information about the syntax, you can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Answer (score -3):

use if statement if x > 0: .. "" else: .