# Floyd's Algorithm in Python

Tags: python

I am not sure how to implement Floyd's algorithm in the following program. It must print a 5x5 array that represents this graph [on page 466](http://books.google.com/books?id=BEhlUfdMNucC&pg=PA466&lpg=PA466&dq=write%20a%20program%20in%20the%20language%20of%20your%20choice%20to%20solve%20the%20all%20pairs%20shortest%20path%20problem%20for%20a%20graph%20with%20five%20nodes&source=bl&ots=UexTc1rovc&sig=TsPYG4UQ-apHIDvHhaGESDeooJY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-xnpUaSiIIe09gTihYCIDQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=write%20a%20program%20in%20the%20language%20of%20your%20choice%20to%20solve%20the%20all%20pairs%20shortest%20path%20problem%20for%20a%20graph%20with%20five%20nodes&f=false) and include a counter which is used to print the total number of comparisons when the algorithm is executed - each execution of the "if" structure counts as one comparison.

Does anyone know how to even start this program? I am not sure how to begin.

Comment: There's a very clear description of the algorithm in pseudocode on the page you linked to. That seems like a good place to start to me.

Comment: @ali_m is right - The pseudocode you linked to is almost Python! With a couple of syntactical replacements you can convert it to valid Python code.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

The following is purely a transcription of the pseudocode you linked. I changed almost nothing.

```
for k in range(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if A[i][k]+A[k][j]<A[i][j]:
                A[i][j]=A[i][k]+A[k][j]
```

Comment: wouldn't this program have to take a lis though? i know this program is the outline of the main program but i cannot figure out how to take a list of inputs from user which includes infinity (500)

Comment: Either set A[i][j]=0 if vertices are not connected (and apropriatelly change the if statement or set A[i][j] to float('inf').

Oh, and of course, google is your friend. Try googling a question about python's infinity rather than asking it outright. The first google hit is

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628026/python-infinity-any-caveats

Answer (score 2):

Translated from the page you linked to,

```
k=0
while (k <= n-1):
    i=0
    while (i<=n-1):
        j=0
        while(j<=n-1):
            if(A[i,k] + A[k,j] < A[i,j]):
                A[i,j] = A[i,k] + A[k,j]
            j += 1
        i += 1
    k += 1
```

NB This is the exact translation to Python. 
Better, more Pythonic code is also possible - see, e.g. 5xum's answer 
which uses the `range` function instead of manually incrementing the loop counters.

Also `A` here would be a 2d matrix (e.g. a `numpy ndarray`).
See more information about numpy [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/)

Comment: wouldn't this program have to take a lis though? i know this program is the outline of the main program but i cannot figure out how to take a list of inputs from user which includes infinity (500