# while loop, run forever or count down

Tags: python, optimization

Is there a better solution to write a while loop that runs forever if the argument is 0 or just runs n times if the argument is an arbitrary n larger 0 than this:

```
x = options.num  # this is the argument (read by Optparse)
if x == 0:
    check = lambda x: True
else:
    check = lambda x: True if x > 0 else False
while check(x):
    print("Hello World")
    x -= 1
```

you can probably combine the lambda into:

```
check = lambda x: True if x > 0 or options.num == 0 else False
```

but then you will still have to count down x, unless you put a if before that.

Comment: `lambda x: True if x > 0 else False` aka `lambda x: x > 0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
n = options.num

while (options.num == 0) or (n > 0):
    print("Hello World")
    n -= 1
```

Essentially we have an infinite loop if `x == 0` or we only run `n` times.

Comment: That won't work. If n is > 0 it needs to stop when it reaches 0.

Comment: I tought he used the variable n two times in the condition. You are right, it does work.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is quite expressive:

```
if x==0:
  x = float("inf") # user says 0 but means infinity

while x>0:
   print "something"
   x -= 1
```

Comment: +1 Yes, that's exactly what I was just writing down, too. ;-) But how about changing that to `x = options.num or float('inf')`? Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628026/python-infinity-any-caveats)

Comment: @tobias_k I think I prefer like it is now. Using a valid value n=0 as a placeholder is, in my opinion, a wrong choice which must me clearly stated in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
def while_function(n):
    if n > 0: n += 1
    while n-1:
        print "something"
        n -= 1
```

Here is demo:

```
>>> while_function(1)
something
>>> while_function(2)
something
something
>>> while_function(0)
something
something
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use `itertools.count`

The trick is easy:

```
from itertools import count
x = options.num  # this is the argument (read by Optparse)
if x:
    loops = xrange(x)
else:
    loops = count()

for i in loops:
    print("Hello World")
```

The code runs looping over iterator. In case of number other than 0, it uses iterator `xrange`,
which yields `x` numbers.

In case of x being 0, we ouse `count` iterator from `itertools`, which is able to retreive infinite
number of numbers.

It can be even shortened (but I leave original version up for readibility):

```
from itertools import count
x = options.num  # this is the argument (read by Optparse)

for i in xrange(x) if x else count():
    print("Hello World")
```

Comment: +1 Nice. Maybe shorter with `loops = xrange(options.num) if options.num else count()`

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, I had similar construct in my editor, but decided to go in more readable way. Short variant added as you have proposed (with leaving `x = options.num` on separate line)

Answer (score 0):

Consider focusing on readability instead of minimal length of the code.  If a body of the loop is trivial I would write

```
if x:
  for i in xrange(x):
    print('Hello, World!')
else:
  while True:
    print('Hello, World!')
```

And if the body is big enough I would extract a function

```
def body():
  print('Hello, World!')

if x:
  for i in xrange(x):
    body()
else:
  while True:
    body()
```