# python map exception continue mapping execution

Tags: python, dictionary, exception, python-3.4

The following example is very simple. I want to execute **map()** with a function which can raise Exception. It will be more clearly with an example :

```
number_list = range(-2,8)

def one_divide_by(n):
    return 1/n

try:
    for number, divide in zip(number_list, map(one_divide_by, number_list)):
        print("%d : %f" % (number, divide))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    # Execution is stopped. I want to continue mapping
    pass
```

When I execute this code I get :

```
-2 : -0.500000
-1 : -1.000000
```

It's due to the 0 in my list. I don't want remove this 0 (because in real case I can't know first if I will get Exception).
Do you know how to **continue mapping after the exception** ?

Comment: if you know what value to substitute for 'infinite' then use `try: return 1/n; except ZeroDivisionError: return yourvalue`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could catch the exception in your function (instead of in the `for` loop) and return `None` (or whatever you choose) if `ZeroDivisionError` is raised:

```
def one_divide_by(n):
    try:
        return 1/n
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return None
```

if you choose to `return None` you need to adapt your format string; `None` can not be formatted with `%f`.

other values you could return (and that would be compatible with your string formatting) are `float('inf')` (or `float('-inf')` depending  on the sign of your numerator) or `float('nan')` - "*inf*inity" or "*n*ot *a* *n*umber".

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628026/python-infinity-any-caveats) you will find some of the caveats of using `float('inf')`.

Comment: I think returning `float('nan')` is probably the best option here. But I guess that it should be mentioned that you need to use [math.isnan()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=math.isnan#math.isnan) to test `nan`.

Answer (score 4):

You can move the `try/except` block inside the function. Example -

```
def one_divide_by(n):
    try:
        return 1/n
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0   #or some other default value.
```

And then call this normally, without a try/except block -

```
for number, divide in zip(number_list, map(one_divide_by, number_list)):
    print("%d : %f" % (number, divide))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can replace `map` instead of changing the definition of your function `one_divide_by`, I would recommend [`more_itertools.map_except`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.map_except):

```py
from more_itertools import map_except

number_list = range(-2,8)

def one_divide_by(n):
    return 1/n

for number, divide in map_except(
        lambda number: (number, one_divide_by(number)),
        number_list,
        ZeroDivisionError
):
    print(number, ':', divide)
```

This prints, as expected:

```
-2 : -0.5
-1 : -1.0
1 : 1.0
2 : 0.5
3 : 0.3333333333333333
4 : 0.25
5 : 0.2
6 : 0.16666666666666666
7 : 0.14285714285714285
```

The function `more_itertools.map_except` accepts a function, an iterable as inputs (just like the built-in `map`) and expected exceptions. When one of those exceptions is raised during the mapping process, the element is simply skipped.

This package can be installed using `pip install more-itertools`, for pip users, or `conda install -c conda-forge more-itertools`, for Conda users.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to define a helper function that accepts a handler for exceptions like this:

```
def map_e(function, *iterables, on_exception=None):
    for elements in zip(*iterables):
        try:
            yield function(*elements)
        except Exception as e:
            yield on_exception(elements, exception=e) \
                if callable(*on_exception) \
                else None


list_a = [1,  2, 5, 1]
list_b = [2, -2, 6, 6]
list_c = [2,  1, 0, 8]


def sum_then_divide(a, b, c):
    return (a + b) / c


def none_on_exception(*args, **kwargs):
    return None


result = list(
    map_e(
        sum_then_divide,
        list_a,
        list_b,
        list_c,
        on_exception=none_on_exception
    )
)

print(result)
```

No need to handle the exception in your main function, and no need to add external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As [ruancomelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65940855/3690024) pointed out, `map_except` can **drop** the offending function call instance from your resulting iterable.  This may not be your the desired behaviour.

If you want the offending function call to still appear in the output stream, you can use function composition to transform the exception into something else.  For instance, this wrapper:

```
def zero_div_protect(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        try:
            return func(*args)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return float('inf')
    return wrapper
```

will take a function (such as `one_divide_by`) and return a new function, wrapping the original function with a `try:...except:` that returns an "exceptional value" when the exception occurs.

```
number_list = range(-2, 8)

def one_divide_by(n):
    return 1/n

for number, divide in zip(number_list, map(zero_div_protect(one_divide_by), number_list)):
    print("%d : %f" % (number, divide))
```

Output:

```
-2 : -0.500000
-1 : -1.000000
0 : inf
1 : 1.000000
2 : 0.500000
3 : 0.333333
4 : 0.250000
5 : 0.200000
6 : 0.166667
7 : 0.142857
```

---

You can also use `zero_div_protect` as a "decorator", which replaces the original function with the wrapped version:

```
number_list = range(-2,8)

@zero_div_protect
def one_divide_by(n):
    return 1/n

for number, divide in zip(number_list, map(one_divide_by, number_list)):
    print("%d : %f" % (number, divide))
```

The output is the same.

---

See also: [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) for more advanced usages.